# downloading large number of files using python

Tags: python, http, python-3.x

test.txt contains the list of files to be downloaded:

```
http://example.com/example/afaf1.tif
http://example.com/example/afaf2.tif
http://example.com/example/afaf3.tif
http://example.com/example/afaf4.tif
http://example.com/example/afaf5.tif
```

How these files can be downloaded using python with maximum download speed?

my thinking was as follows:

```
import urllib.request
with open ('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(line)
```

What after that?How to select download directory?

Answer (score 2):

Select a path to your desired output directory (`output_dir`). In your for loop split every url on `/` character and use the last peace as the filename. Also open the files for writing in binary mode `wb` since the `response.read()` returns `bytes`, not `str`.

```
import os
import urllib.request

output_dir = 'path/to/you/output/dir'

with open ('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(line)
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, line.split('/')[-1])
        with open(output_file, 'wb') as writer:
            writer.write(response.read())
```

**Note:**

Downloading multiple files can be faster if you use multiple threads since the download is rarely using the full bandwidth of your internet connection._

Also if the files you are downloading are pretty big you should probably stream the read (reading chunk by chunk). As @Tiran commented you should use `shutil.copyfileobj(response, writer)` instead of `writer.write(response.read())`.

I would only add that you should probably always specify the length parameter too: `shutil.copyfileobj(response, writer, 5*1024*1024) # (at least 5MB)` since the default value of 16kb is really small and it will just slow things down.

Comment: writer.write(response.read()) is a bad idea because it loads the entire file into memory and then flushes it out to the file system. You should use shutil.copyfileobj(response, writer) instead.

Comment: @Tiran Yes, I wrote that in the note. It doesn't make a difference if the files are small (the OP is downloading a list of images). But you're right I should update the answer.

Comment: Why do you think that 5 MB is faster? 16kb is fine. A smaller buffer uses more syscalls but benefits from L2 and L3 cache affinity. If you are concerned about speed, you have to resort to other means like zero-copy with sendfile(2) and AIO.

Comment: @Tiran Because I tested it on > 100 machines (different HDD) and 10 different networks :) I ended up using 24MB for LAN connections and 5MB chunks for WAN. That's what my statistics said is the peak performance.

Comment: @Tiran Of course, you may get different results for your network setup/os/server/hdd... I just wanted to emphasise that the limit value of 16kb was slower than bigger chunks on every setup I tested (for large files).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me: (note that name must be absolute, for example 'afaf1.tif')

```
import urllib,os
def download(baseUrl,fileName,layer=0):
    print 'Trying to download file:',fileName
    url = baseUrl+fileName
    name = os.path.join('foldertodwonload',fileName)
    try:
        #Note that folder needs to exist
        urllib.urlretrieve (url,name)
    except:
        # Upon failure to download retries total 5 times
        print 'Download failed'
        print 'Could not download file:',fileName
        if layer > 4:
            return
        else:
            layer+=1
        print 'retrying',str(layer)+'/5'
        download(baseUrl,fileName,layer)
    print fileName+' downloaded'

for fileName in nameList:
    download(url,fileName)
```

Moved unnecessary code out from try block

Comment: Never ever use a bare except in your code! It shadows other mistakes like typos, too.

Comment: I know right. but above there is tested and working. Anyway i'm not sure what type of error should be used so until someone points that out, it'll be bare.